# How do I change font in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, fonts, jupyter-notebook

How do I change font in Jupyter Notebook? I want to change the font in Jupyter Notebook and I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 6):

I know that you can do that with the `jupyterthemes` package. Please see below for a sample of how to install the package and change the font.

```
pip install jupyterthemes
# set font/font-size of markdown (text cells) and notebook (interface)
# see sans-serif & serif font tables below
jt -tf merriserif -tfs 10 -nf ptsans -nfs 13
```

You may find other fonts listed [on the github repository.](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes#command-line-usage)

The first purpose of this package is to change the theme of jupyter though.
Maybe it would be the opportunity to try a background less aggressive for the eyes than the defautl one. I personnaly run :

```
jupyter-theme -t oceans16 -T
```